# Php Slim framework rooter is not working

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I don't know why my slim app is acting strange, all urls are considered as index "/", Example:

i have those 3 urls :

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response){return "index";});
$app->get('/user', function ($request, $response){return "user";});
$app->get('/superuser', function ($request, $response){return "superuser";});
```

if i go to localhost or localhost/user or localhost/superuser or event any other url localhost/ANYTHING ; I always get index with HTTP STATUS 200

Help Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callbacks should return objects implementing `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`, while they return strings.

Thus instead of

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response){return "index";});
```

You should have

```
$app->get('/', function ($request, $response) {
    return $response->write('index');
});
```

I also suggest to display errors, at least for development version. Here is the [link, that describes how to do that](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/handlers/error.html).

Comment: Yeah you need to return the Response object with the modified status code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all guys for your suggestions but i found that the problem was due to my bad command to run the built-in php server i was running this command :
    `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 public/index.php`
instead of this one: `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php`
if someone can explain to me what -t public does i'd apreaciate :)

Comment: `-t` option is used to specify an explicit document root. If not provided, and URI does not specify the file, index.php or index.html is returned.